# Complete bipartite graph, edges and average degree

Tags: graph-theory

How many edges does $K_{m,n}$ have? What is the average degree of $K_{m,n}$? For which values of $m, n$ does $K_{m,n}$ have an Euler circuit?

Let's take $m = 2$ and $n = 2$. I know that the number of edges is equal to $m n$. But how do I work out the average degree of $K_{m,n}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the number of edges is $mn$, so the average degree is $\frac{2mn}{m+n}$.

In order for the graph to have an euler circuit the degree of every vertex must be even, so it is equivalent to $m$ and $n$ being both even.